# Better way of getting a list of ids

Tags: java, collections, guava

This is the sample object i have

```
public class Dummy {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    /**
     * @return the id.
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set.
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set.
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

My problem is this I have a list of these objects and I need to fetch the list of ids present in that object inside the list. I could easily do this by

```
List<Long> ids = Lists.newArrayList();
for(Dummy dummy: dummyList){
 ids.add(dummy.getId()); 
}
```

I am wondering if it can be done by using alternative approach(instead of using a for loop may be?) than what i have come up with may be using `Iterables` or `Collections` filtering?

EDIT: I am interested in knowing how it can be done differently than i have come up with.

Comment: if you want one with while i can do that for you.

Comment: You could create a custom class for your collection and define an enumeration for the class that enumerates over the ids [tutorial here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CreatingCustomEnumerations.htm) but that is going to be many more lines of code to set up. (The call itself will be less though).

Comment: Maybe using dependency injection?

Comment: You can use Iterables.transform with a custom Function but it will produce more than four lines (or one very long unreadable line). If you want something shorter, wait for Java 8. I believe you'll be able to express that in one or two lines with closures.

Comment: Underneath the hood it would be a for loop still so there is no real savings.  I would do what I suggested below, make a method, you can always replace the body of the method with something "smaller" at a later date.

Comment: I edited my question. i am looking for alternative options i might have miscommunicated by mentioning shorter in my question, i apologize for that.

Comment: @TofuBeer If you defined a custom iteration that yields the ids rather than the object itself then you could do lazy loading of the ids, which could potentially have a lot of savings performance-wise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Using Guava

You can use `Iterables.transform` to obtain an Iterable of your indices:

```
List<Dummy> dummyList = Lists.newArrayList();
Iterable<Long> idList = Iterables.transform(dummyList, new Function<Dummy, Long>() {
    public Long apply(Dummy dummy) { return dummy.getId(); };
});
```

But it seems really overkill for that. You gain one line and you lose in readability.

### Using Java 8

Since Java 8 you have closure and you are able to write this in a terser way.

```
List<Long> idList = dummyList
            .stream()
            .map(Dummy::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i dont really care for the line count i edited my question to reflect that. i was interested in more in the alternative approach

Comment: Your Java8 example is missing .collect(Collectors.toList()). Cannot convert from Stream<Long> to List<Long>.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make it shorter, that is the smallest amount of work you can have to get the job done.

What you could do, if you find that you are doing that in a number of places then make a method out of it:

```
public static List<Long> getIds(final List<Dummy> dummyList)
{
    List<Long> ids = Lists.newArrayList();
    for(Dummy dummy: dummyList){
        ids.add(dummy.getId());   
    } 
}
```

And then:

```
List<Long> ids = getIds(dummyList);
```

Edit: If you do find a different way later you would just replace the method body and "magically" all of the places you are doing that will all be using the new method.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness: you could also use [`LambdaJ`](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) to make it a one-liner:

```
List<Long> ids = extract(dummyList, on(Dummy.class).getId());
```

See more details on [LambdaJ's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures#Converting,_indexing_and_sorting_items).

Please note that this solution might look nicer than a for loop, but performs much worse because it employs proxies behind the scenes, so I wouldn't use it if the code is performance critical. See some analysis on the performance penalty incurred by LambdaJ [here](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/PerformanceAnalysis).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Long> idList = dummyList
   .stream()
   .map(d -> d.getId())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is this better than the 2013 answer? If so, why?